# using hobby MF font with LaTeX, adding accented characters

Tags: fonts, metafont

I created a hobby font with metafont. I would like to include some accents in the font, but I am not sure what is the standard way for accomplishing that (gogle was not very helpful), so that the font works with LaTeX (pdflatex, if needs be).

1. How can I load the font in LaTeX, so that it is used for characters which it defines, and some fallback font (with warning) is used for the rest? (in plain, I do just `\font\myFont=myFont \myFont`, but characters which are not defined are not typeset at all)
2. How to define shapes of accents, placed atop glyphs with `\'`, ...? I imagine this has to do with font encodings, such as `T1`?
3. I found [virtual fonts HOWTO](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/info/virtualfontshowto/virtualfontshowto.txt), which only mentions creating virtual font from PS fonts. Can I use metafont-generated fonts as well?
4. Do I need virtual fonts, or is there an easier alternative?
5. **EDIT:** I am considering using approach (and some scripts) from Lilypond: trace metafont with mftrace, then use fontforge scripts to create an OpenType font. (it needs mf log reading hackery, but could work) If I include accents as combining characters in OTF, they will work automatically with XeTeX? It looks like the easiest now, am I just being eluded?

I am sorry if the questions are confused, I am new to fonts. Thanks for any pointers --

**PS:** I tried loading the font with XeLaTeX+fontspec but I get (ignota.tfm is in the current dir):

```
fontspec.cfg loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
\zf@set@font@type ...onttype \zf@basefont \zf@tfm 
                                                  \or \zf@atsuitrue \ifnum \...
l.4 \setmainfont{ignota}
```

**PPS:** everybody loves screenshots :-)

[image: lorem ipsum]

Comment: Do you want to use the font with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX or even with pdfLaTeX? You may use every OTF font with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX using e.g. [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec). But to use a font with pdfLaTeX you need a `fd` file and a `map` file. See [fntguide](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf) for more information about _font definition files_ and font encodings. Accent combinations would be OT1, but you may add a virtual font to create a T1 font. See [fontinstallationguide](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontinstallationguide) for information about virtual fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial solution meanwhile. Use the `T1` (=Cork?) encoding which is 8-bit but sufficiently covers West/Central European languages (all I need now).

1. Within the Metafont file, define characters as `beginchar(##,...)`, where `##` is number in the T1 encoding (e.g. [here, pg. 23](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf), or in [tex256.enc](http://tug.org/fontname/tex256.enc)), so for instance é is 233 and so on.

   Accented letters like ā not directly covered by `T1` are composed from accents within the font (positions 0-11)
2. Then, introduce the font to LaTeX (I used [calligra.sty](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fundus/calligra.sty) as template) and define a shorthand for activating it:

   ```
   % 10.0 is scaling factor; I guess I have something wrong as it is must be that big...
   \DeclareFontShape{T1}{ignota}{m}{n}{<->s*[10.0]ignota}{}
   \DeclareRobustCommand\ignota{
      \fontfamily{ignota}%
      \fontencoding{T1}%
      \selectfont
   }
   ```

   Generating metrics and bitmap fonts from ignota.mf is handled by kpathsea automatically.

The following text uses `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage{ignota}`; the accents were all input as utf8 accented characters; work with both LaTeX and pdfLaTeX. Oh yes, I know it looks horrible typographically: 
[image: rendered PDF]

**Still unclear to me:** how to convert the font to outline font? Is running `mftrace` enough? Can I use the font with XeTeX directly, without other conversions?